# In database my query getting first row When i grouped

Tags: sql

```
SELECT
    EVENT_ID, COUNT(*), SEQUENCE_NBR 
FROM
    ALERTS  
WHERE 
    ACKNOWLEDGED = 0 
    AND SRC_EXT = '7878'  
GROUP BY
    EVENT_ID 
ORDER BY 
    COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Running this query to get id,count and sequence number. by group by event id and count i am getting sequence number first row .

```
+----------+--------------+
| EVENT_ID | SEQUENCE_NBR |
+----------+--------------+
|      150 |         9752 |
|      150 |         9764 |
|      150 |         9775 |
|      170 |         9755 |
|      170 |         9763 |
|      170 |         9774 |
|      217 |         9748 |
|      217 |         9759 |
|      217 |         9770 |
|      218 |         9751 |
|      218 |         9762 |
|      218 |         9773 |
|      273 |         9749 |
|      273 |         9760 |
|      273 |         9771 |
|      285 |         9750 |
|      285 |         9761 |
|      285 |         9772 |
+----------+--------------+
```

This is my data in db by using above query

```
+----------+----------+--------------+
| EVENT_ID | COUNT(*) | SEQUENCE_NBR |
+----------+----------+--------------+
|      150 |        3 |         9752 |
|      170 |        3 |         9755 |
|      217 |        3 |         9748 |
|      218 |        3 |         9751 |
|      273 |        3 |         9749 |
|      285 |        3 |         9750 |
+----------+----------+--------------+
```

i need data in same format with seuence number should

```
150 |        3 |         9775
```

Comment: Use `MAX(SEQUENCE_NBR)` in a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Your query is malformed.  The `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` columns are incompatible.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? That query is invalid standard SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is malformed.  You have `SEQUENCE_NBR` in the `SELECT`, but it is not in the `GROUP BY`.  In most databases (including the more recent versions of MySQL), this generates an error.  Happily that is so.

If you want the maximum `SEQUENCE_NBR`, then use the `MAX()` function:

```
SELECT EVENT_ID, COUNT(*), MAX(SEQUENCE_NBR) as SEQUENCE_NBR
FROM ALERTS  
WHERE ACKNOWLEDGED = 0 AND
      SRC_EXT = '7878'  
GROUP BY EVENT_ID 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try like below

```
    SELECT
    EVENT_ID, COUNT(*), SEQUENCE_NBR 
FROM
    ALERTS  
WHERE 
    ACKNOWLEDGED = 0 
    AND SRC_EXT = '7878'  
GROUP BY
    EVENT_ID 
ORDER BY 
    COUNT(*) DESC,SEQUENCE_NBR desc;
```

Comment: It is showing data as
'+-----+----------+--------------+
| cnt | EVENT_ID | SEQUENCE_NBR |
+-----+----------+--------------+
|   3 |      150 |         9755 |
+-----+----------+--------------+'

Comment: @uma check now it seems i misunderstood your point